# ScrollView not showing everything and is cut off

Tags: react-native

I need this screen to ***show all the contents*** that is inside the scrollview, I've tried everything setting ScrollView's flexGrow to 1, parent view's flex to 100. The scrollview is scrolling down until iteration of Bark Central Dog Park & Cafe but it is cut off to half and can't scroll any further, also I noticed that the text HELP ME can not be found too. Thank you so much, as this problem has been bothering me and my progress in react native.

Please tell me what I should do and where I have gone wrong. Thank you again!

NotificationScreen.js

```
export default class NotificationScreen extends Component 
{
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation;
        const {} = state;
        return {  
          header: null,
        };

}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.parentContainer}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: '5%', marginTop: '5%'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('JobFeedScreen')}>
                        <Entypo name="chevron-thin-left" color={Colors.red} size={30} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <View style={{marginLeft: 80,}}>
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'CoreSansD65Heavy',color: Colors.semiGray, fontSize: 25,}}> Ty, Next</Text>
                    </View>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('LaunchScreenStack')} style={{marginLeft: 87,marginRight: '5%',}}>
                        <SimpleLineIcons name='bubbles' color={Colors.red} size={30} /> 
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{marginLeft: '5%'}}>
                <Text style={styles.notificationHeader}> Notifications</Text>
            </View>

            <ScrollView  horizontal={false} overScrollMode={'auto'}>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>Anteriore, Inc.</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>The Palace Manila</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>Boozy.ph</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>Pet warehouse PH</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>Bark Central Dog Park & Cafe</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>Pet warehouse PH</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notifPlace}>
                    <View style={styles.notifTextPlace}>

                    </View>
                    <Text style ={styles.text}>Bark Central Dog Park & Cafe</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <Text> PLEASE HELP ME </Text>
               <Text> PLEASE HELP ME </Text>   
               <Text> PLEASE HELP ME </Text>            
               <Text> PLEASE HELP ME </Text>   
        </ScrollView>
        </View>



    );
}
```

NotificationScreenStyles.js

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Metrics, ApplicationStyles, Colors } from '../../Themes/'

export default StyleSheet.create({
  ...ApplicationStyles.screen,
  container: {
paddingBottom: Metrics.baseMargin
  },
  logo: {
    marginTop: Metrics.doubleSection,
    height: Metrics.images.logo,
    width: Metrics.images.logo,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
  centered: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  parentContainer: {
    flex:1, 
    backgroundColor: Colors.white
  },
  notificationHeader: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
    fontFamily: 'CoreSansD45Medium',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.gray,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  notifPlace: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
    width: '100%', 
    height: '12%',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: Colors.buttonGray,
  },
  notifTextPlace: {
    width:60,
    height:60,
    borderRadius: 60/2, 
    backgroundColor:Colors.buttonGray ,
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
    marginLeft: '5%', 
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'CoreSansD45Medium',
    fontSize: 15, 
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    color: Colors.gray,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  text2: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'CoreSansD35Regular',
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
})
```

Screenshot 1:

[SC1](https://ibb.co/XD0CBhy)

Screenshot 2: ( it only scrolls up to here )

[SC2](https://ibb.co/T0Qr3zQ)

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of your simulator ?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya I have uploaded the screenshot , please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in scroll view of react native, use a `paddingBottom : 100` in the styles of the scroll view.

The 100 can be set to any value according the content you have

Comment: tried adding it today, did not work. I added touchableopacity from a to j in my items, it only got to show A. Also tried changing the paddingbottom to 500 still wont show...

Comment: what happens when you add more items inside the scroll view ? the paddingbottom is for the scroll view

Comment: the listview becomes bigger yes I added it in scrollview and tried it.

Comment: are the new items shown or are they hidden just like your text ?

Comment: some that I added were shown but some also are not. I hope they fix this asap

Comment: this is not a proper solution

Comment: for horizontal scrollview, add `paddingRight`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your StyleSheet and screenshot of what you are seeing.

Test to add 
height = Dimensions.get('window').height 
to your parentContainer

Also try paddingBottom to your scrollview StyleSheet

Comment: provided the stylesheet in my question here, I have tried the paddingBottom and increased its numbers, but it doesn't work all items wont show. I tried adding more items to be sure, but it still doesnt show everything.

Comment: did you try this: height = Dimensions.get('window').height

Comment: to me it looks like your parentContainer is out of the view.

Comment: Ill try it when I get home, Im travelling right now and will try it asap.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem and what finally fixed it for me was making sure my scrollview wasn't the last component in my layout. So I added an invisible component (with a set height to offset the amount of scrollview content I couldn't see) right after my scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have added a height to the wrapped component of the ScrollView.It worked for me

eg:-

```
<View style={{ height: hp(500) }}>
   <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {filteredItems.map((item) => <Text style={styles.listItemText}>{item.title}</Text>)}
   </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. I find that ***setting a height value(either `height` or `minHeight`) in percentage `%` values is what triggers this problem for a vertical ScrollView.***

Changing this to normal dp (or numeric) values takes the problem away.

The downside is that it may not be the best fix for many use cases, especially if you really need responsiveness.

***If you really need that percentage for your view, set it as `paddingBottom` and not `height`.*** It's contrary to the intended use but well, it serves as a simple work-around

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

What fixed it for me was adding `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1,paddingRight:100}}` to my scrollview.

Hope it helps someone too!!

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

just add like this :

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ width:'100%',height:'500%'}}>
```